# pigeonhole principle inequation problem

Tags: analysis

Hey guys maybe some of you can give me some tipps to solve this one I have really no clue how to attend to solve it.

$$\forall x\in \ \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q},\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N},\exists(p,q)\in\ \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}: 1\leq q\leq n \ \land \left \vert{ x -\frac{p}{q}}\right\vert\le\frac1{nq}$$

Tip given by teacher: Look at the set $\left\{{\ell x−\lfloor\ell x\rfloor : \ell \in  \mathbb{N}\cap[1, n+ 1]}\right\}$, where $\lfloor \ell x\rfloor$ is the biggest natural number
that's smaller then $\ell x$. Use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: WLOG consider $x \in (0,1)$. Now, divide this interval into $n$ small subintervals of length $1/n$. The set your teacher gave to you has $n+1$ elements... so what do you conclude?

Comment: I think you are missing something at the end, ∣∣x−p/q∣∣??

Comment: @WLOG i do not understand it correctly.

Comment: ∣x−p/q∣ is not a statement, has no logical value, it needs a relation next to it like ∣x−p/q∣<m or something...

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov yep its wrong one second its smaller equal 1/nq

Answer (score 1):

See the set your teacher provided, there are n+1 elements in interval (0,1), so there are at least two of them with difference between less then 1/n. Let say $$|(ℓ_1x−⌊ℓ_1x⌋)-(ℓ_2x−⌊ℓ_2x⌋)|<1/n$$
$$|(ℓ_1-ℓ_2)x-p|<1/n, p∈Z$$
Since $ℓ_1,ℓ_2∈N∩[1,n+1]$ then $|ℓ_1-ℓ_2|=q∈N∩[1,n] $ so divide all by q
$$∣x−p/q∣≤1/(nq)$$

Comment: I Just not hundred percent understand how you get from step one to step two

Comment: ⌊ℓ1x⌋ and ⌊ℓ2x⌋ are in Z, so is their subtraction p

Comment: Okj and how did you know it has to be smaller then 1/n f